# Reading 2 cell values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe like below

```
Name   SecondName  RollNo
-----  ----------  ------
Jon     George      145
Adam    Michael     189
Sam     Obama       191
```

How can i pick the SecondName and RollNo for the Name i give as input

`df['Name'][1]` gives me `Adam`, but how can i get the other 2 corresponding values from the cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your index as `Name`, then use the `loc` accessor:

```
df_by_name = df.set_index('Name')

print(df_by_name.loc['Adam'])

SecondName    Michael
RollNo            189
Name: Adam, dtype: object
```

This will work whether or not your names are unique. If you have duplicate entries for a name, the output will be a dataframe. If there is only one entry for a given name, the output will be a series, as above.